# MySQL - NOW() different value if its in trigger or in select

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with MySQL NOW() function

if i run:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

i get the value:

```
2015-11-24 13:35:00 (correct value with Swedish winter-time)
```

But if i use NOW() in a trigger function to update a timestamp column when another column changes like this:

```
SET NEW.timestamp = NOW();
```

i get the value:

```
2015-11-24 12:35:00
```

How can i solve this or why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 1):

To get current date and time using NOW(), please set the timezone as per your country to get the correct date and time.
Please check the link [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/)

If you want to change the MySQL server’s time zone to adjust the current date and time returned by the NOW()  function, you use the following statement:

SET time_zone = your_time_zone;

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has multiple ways of specifying a timezone - the server has a default time zone and each client can also specify their own time zone on a per-connection basis.

I think that your `SELECT` is using the time zone specified by your client connection, while the trigger is using the server's default time zone.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html